# Git Protocol with Team Foundation Server 2013

Tags: node.js, git, tfs, npm

I recently upgraded our TFS system to TFS 2013. I have a set of developers that are developing some tools using NodeJS which are consumed internally. They previously had their source on an internal Gitorious server. The tools they developed are installed by other devs by running an `npm install` with the Gitorious repo url:

```
npm install git://gitorious.corp.local/project/repo.git
```

Since TFS 2013 supported our old TFVC and now has Git we've moved everyone onto a single source control server. The team has migrated their repository and still want to be able to have the install command. Run similar to this:

```
npm install git://tfs2013.corp.local:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_git/Repo
```

This does not appear to work. Here's the error:

```
npm ERR! git clone git://tfs2013.corp.local:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_git/Repo Cloning into bare repository 'C:\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-tfs-8080-tfs-DefaultCollection-Project-git-repo-fbbf0c4b'...
npm ERR! git clone git://tfs2013.corp.local:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_git/Repo
npm ERR! git clone git://tfs2013.corp.local:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_git/Repo fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: HTTP
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "git://tfs2013.corp.local:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_git/Repo"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.4.1
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: HTTP
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Source\git\sumtotal-module\npm-debug.log
```

**Does TFS support a git protocol?**

I tried the same command with http:

```
npm install http://tfs2013.corp.local:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_git/Repo
```

It fails with this error:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed http://tfs2013.corp.local:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_git/Repo
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 401
npm ERR! fetch failed http://tfs2013.corp.local:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_git/Repo
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 401
```

I haven't been able to find any information on how to set up the git protocol in IIS or if it needs to be enabled in TFS's configuration.

**Is this possible?** I have yet to find an article or word that says yes/no on this.

Our internal standards team really does not want to have multiple version control systems floating around so I would really like to figure out if this is a limitation of TFS 2013 and if there is planned future support.

To a limited extent is there anything we can do with Node's Package Manager to make it work with TFS's git repositories?

**EDIT/UPDATE**

All git commands involving actions against the remote using `HTTP` protocol are working correctly, clone, fetch, pull, & push.

```
git clone http://tfs2013.corp.local:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_git/Repo
```

When using doing the following

```
git clone git://tfs2013.corp.local:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_git/Repo testDirectory
```

It fails:

```
Cloning into 'testDirectory'...
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: HTTP
```

Given the error that the `npm` command produces I'm not surprised that the `git clone` fails when I use the `git` protocol.

My next step is to fire up wireshark and see if I can get the response that TFS is sending. I'd rather not use wireshark so if there is a suggestion to grab the response in another manner I'd appreciate it.

**WIRESHARK OUTPUT - RESPONSE FROM TFS**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Wondering if I need to setup anything in IIS for the git protocol...

**UPDATE**

Looks like this may be a NPM issue instead of a TFS issue. Using git:// implies ssh which TFS 2013 **does not** support. I didn't think of using wireshark on the http request. I should've known this as it was telling me the response was 401 but the request by NPM couldn't be authenticated!

I opened an issue with NPM here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7557

Comment: Have you tried to `git clone` the repo manually and see if it works?

Comment: @TimothyGu Normal git operations work fine using the http protocol. I've updated the question to properly answer you question.

Comment: This is still an issue in TFS 2015. TFS 2015 Update 3 adds SSH support, which may fix the problem; we're on update 1. We are using git+http:// for our commit-ish, but I have no guarantee that doesn't try to failover to SSL or vice versa.

Comment: I saw that in the commit notes when installing it yesterday. Weird that this comment is posted today! I'll have to re-try it out. Perhaps MS finally has listened to all the complaints!